# Endianness order. How will these bytes be represented?

Tags: endianness

Given the hexadecimal bytes 0x12345678, copy the bytes to memory using big-endian order.

Address         Content

0x00400003        0x78

0x00400002        0x56

0x00400001        0x34

0x00400000        0x12

Is that right?

Comment: Depends on what `0x12345678` endianness is in.

Comment: Yes, but it's probably in big-endian (we usually don't write numbers like `0x7867453412`). Based on that, the OP's solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In big-endian, the most significant byte (`12`) should come first, and then the rest should come in decreasing order of significance.

If the given number is in big-endian byte-order (and probably it is), **your solution is right**, as it will look like this:

```
00400000|00400001|00400002|00400003
--------+--------+--------+--------
   12   |   34   |   56   |   78
```

If you had to arrange the bytes in little endian, the arrangement would be reversed:

```
00400000|00400001|00400002|00400003
--------+--------+--------+--------
   78   |   56   |   34   |   12
```

Note that in this arrangement, only the order of *bytes* is reversed, but the order of *nibbles* (4-bit regions = hexadecimal digits) remains the same.

You can read more in [this Wikipedia page about endianness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).